# Do I need to include my PHP class in every file

Tags: php, class

I have a class for managing a database. In this class I define the connection and I have various functions for different kind of fetches/retrieving of data.

I usually have a php file for ajax operations and through that I include the files with the functions I need and I pass as a variable to these functions the instance of my class.

Then I use that instance in the functions to make queries and fetch data from the database.

My question is: do I need to include the class declaration in the file with the functions?
The structure is as the following... more or less. Basically do I need to include the databaseClass.php in the functionCollection.php

```
databaseClass.php
<?php

class MyDBManager
{
    private $database   = 'db';
    private $host       = 'host'; 
    private $username   = 'siteguest';
    private $password   = 'psw';
    private $options    = array();
    ...
    function __construct(){}

    function runQuery($statement){}

    function fetchRow(){}
    ...
}
?>

livesearch.php
<?php
    include_once("databaseClass.php");
    include_once("something.php");

    $var1 = $_POST['id'];
    $var2 = $_POST['date'];
    $var3 = $_POST['time'];

    $database = new MyDBManager();

    somefunction($database, $var1, $var2, $var3);
    ...
?>

functionCollection.php
<?php
    include_once("databaseClass.php");
    include_once("misc.php");

    function nameExists($database, $var1, $var2, $var2){}
    ...
?>
```

Comment: Just look at PHP's [autoloading](http://nl3.php.net/autoload) features :)

Comment: Did anybody help you out here? Can you give some credit?

Answer (score 0):

No, the file containing the class definition must be loaded exactly *once*, anywhere. Once the file has been loaded and the class definition has been parsed it is available from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Autoloading is designed to prevent this exact problem. When you try to instantiate a class PHP will try to autoload that class before throwing an exception.

Before autoloading we would have to include all our class files. From the PHP documentation:

> In PHP 5, this is no longer necessary. You may define an __autoload()
>   function which is automatically called in case you are trying to use a
>   class/interface which hasn't been defined yet. By calling this
>   function the scripting engine is given a last chance to load the class
>   before PHP fails with an error.

However, there's a better option `spl_autoload_register` allows you to register multiple autoloaders which will be executed one by one until the class is not found and then an exception will be thrown.

There is now a standard in PHP called `PSR-0 Standard` and came along with PHPs support of namespaces.

You should read this article, it gives a breif history and explains how to implement your own autoloader. http://phpmaster.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/

If you get time have a look at some real world autoloaders to learn more, for example Yii or Symfony's framework autoloader.